# Order by date in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sorting, last-modified, datecreated

i want to sort records based on LastModifiedDate or CreatedDate, i want the latest of the two should appear on top. i tried with `order by CreatedDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC` but this does not shows the latest of them on top, it gives first priority to lastmodifieddate and then to CreatedDate

Comment: Please show us your query too

Comment: Logically lastmodified is always latest.

Comment: what if there is any new record being added, in that case the lastmodified will be null and createddate will have the latest (todays date)

Answer (score 1):

You can may be compare 2 dates in 2 columns and pick whichever is latest

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN lastmodifiedDate > createdDate THEN lastmodifiedDate
        ELSE createdDate
   END AS LatestDate
FROM yourtable
```

Sorry i forgot that you need to order by. Then you can try below

```
select columns from yourtable order by CASE WHEN lastmodifiedDate > createdDate THEN lastmodifiedDate
        ELSE createdDate
   END AS LatestDate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Case statement in the Order By clause, for example:

```
order by 
    case when CreatedDate > LastModifiedDate then CreatedDate else LastModifiedDate end DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT,CREATION_DATE DATE,LAST_MODIFIED_DATE DATE)
INSERT INTO @A
VALUES 
(1,'2016/06/06','2016/06/06'),
(2,'2016/06/06','2016/06/07'),
(3,'2016/06/06','2016/06/05')

SELECT  S.* FROM 
(
SELECT  A.ID,A.CREATION_DATE,A.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
        CASE
            WHEN A.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE > A.CREATION_DATE THEN A.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
            ELSE A.CREATION_DATE 
        END AS ORDER_DATE
FROM    @A A
) S
ORDER BY S.ORDER_DATE DESC
```